# How to call a external javascript function from aspx page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a *javascript* file `file.js` and I have a function `FunctionfromJSpage()` in that *js* page, first from *onclick* I was calling the function `aspxPageFunction();` then from this function I need to call `FunctionfromJSpage();` which is located in `file.js`.
I tried like this in `default.aspx`

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../page/file.js"></script>
  <script  type="text/javascript">
      function aspxPageFunction() { 
         //my code..
         FunctionfromJSpage(); 
      } 
  </script>
</head>
```

But I am unable to call that function.

Comment: When do you want that function to be called ??

Comment: seriously, google it. you can find many related results.

Comment: even of this site !!! http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+call+a+external+javascript+function+from+aspx+page%3F

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you call a Javascript function from an ASPX control event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612124/how-do-you-call-a-javascript-function-from-an-aspx-control-event)

Comment: Here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297189/how-to-use-an-external-javascript-file-in-asp-net/11297391#11297391

Comment: sorry guys. i posted question wrongly previous, now i edited it. my reqirement is to call a function which is in external java script from default.aspx page

Answer (score 3):

harish,

I think what you're looking for is to add the function you've now defined (as Quentin pointed out) to an attribute of an existing asp control. For example:

```
<td>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClientClick="YourFunction(); " Text="ClickMe"/>
</td>
```

You can do all sorts of things using this kind of methodology. It all depends on what you want to do. If you're trying to get something to happen when a user puts text in a textbox, you'll need to research the OnTextChanged event, dropdowns have the onchange event..perhaps a crash course in asp events might be useful to help you understand more about *where* to attach such things.

For client side [(javascript events)](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp).

For server side - what we're talking about here -  [(asp events)](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_events.asp).

It looks like you're just starting to figure out the client server relationship and what you need to do to make things happen (I could be *very* wrong there though). If this is the case, I wish you well! I agree with the other posters - you should explore Google and this site a bit more, as these are VITAL resources to finding breakthrough on your coding endeavors.

-sf

Comment: thanks sf for ur reply and suggessions, i tried these things bt it didnt worked well, the simple thing i need is to call a function located in a external javascript file from default.aspx page javascript.

Comment: That should be fine, you'll just need to make sure that your aspx page loads before the function call is made (or else your function won't be defined)

Answer (score 2):

The code you have in your script element **defines** a function.

You say that you have defined it in file.js. To call it you just `callFunction()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../page/file.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    callFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: I know that this is super old, but I have a question - why can you not call the function in the first script tag that identifies the source page?

Comment: @Jake — By editing file.js? You can. The question was using a second script element though.

Comment: I see now that the original question has two script tags - thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Add the onload attribute to your body, this will call your function when the page loads `<body onload="callFunction()">`

or in codebehind

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "scriptKey", "callFunction();",true);
```

Have a look at this great article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11098/Use-Call-RegisterStartUpScript-RegisterClientScrip

Comment: hi.. i want to call that javascript function from default.aspx page not from default.aspx.vb/.cs

Comment: When do you want the function to be called onload, onclick, when?

Comment: first from onclick i was calling the function "call();" then from this function i need to call "callFunction();" which is located in "file.js". i hope u understood my requirement.